# how to write a list to local storage in flutter using get storage?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

In my app i am using API Auth and when user logged in i want to store the user info in local storage using `get_storage` package. so how can i store a list of objects. what i need is to store the list when user logged in and read that file afterwards in the app.

I've tried to encode the json and assign it to `log.write('user', json.encode(value.body))` but the result of which it gives the list but with all items there is "" sign. like `"{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"Admin\",....` result.  how can i set it appropriately?

user model

```
import 'role_model.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> usersFromJsonFromModel(String str) =>
    List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((json) => User.fromJson(json)));
String usersToJsonFromModel(List<User> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((e) => e.toJson())));

class User {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  String? emailVerifiedAt;
  String? twoFactorConfirmedAt;
  String? currentTeamId;
  String? profilePhotoPath;
  String? warehouseId;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? profilePhotoUrl;
  List<Roles>? roles;

  User(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.username,
      this.email,
      this.emailVerifiedAt,
      this.twoFactorConfirmedAt,
      this.currentTeamId,
      this.profilePhotoPath,
      this.warehouseId,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.profilePhotoUrl,
      this.roles});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    emailVerifiedAt = json['email_verified_at'];
    twoFactorConfirmedAt = json['two_factor_confirmed_at'];
    currentTeamId = json['current_team_id'];
    profilePhotoPath = json['profile_photo_path'];
    warehouseId = json['warehouse_id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    profilePhotoUrl = json['profile_photo_url'];
    if (json['roles'] != null) {
      roles = <Roles>[];
      json['roles'].forEach((v) {
        roles!.add(Roles.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['username'] = username;
    data['email'] = email;
    data['email_verified_at'] = emailVerifiedAt;
    data['two_factor_confirmed_at'] = twoFactorConfirmedAt;
    data['current_team_id'] = currentTeamId;
    data['profile_photo_path'] = profilePhotoPath;
    data['warehouse_id'] = warehouseId;
    data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    data['profile_photo_url'] = profilePhotoUrl;
    if (roles != null) {
      data['roles'] = roles!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

api call

```
Future loginAuth(String email, String password) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}login");
  final loginState = GetStorage();
  final response = await http
      .post(url,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
          },
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
          }))
      .then((value) {
    var data = value.body;
    if (value.statusCode == 200) {
      loginState.write('login', true);
      Get.snackbar(
          "success", "Logged in as ${json.decode(value.body)['username']}");
      print(json.decode(value.body));
      Get.to(Index());
    } else if (value.statusCode == 404) {
      Get.snackbar("failed", "${json.decode(value.body)['message']}");
      print('bad login not workng, ${value.body}');
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Failed", "Failed to Login, Try Again");
      print('bad login, ${value.body}');
    }
  });
}

Future logoutAuth() async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}login");
  final loginState = GetStorage();
}
```

so is there a way to store list in local storage or do i have to store every items separately? and if there is how can i read or access that storage in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save `value.body` in local storage because it is already json and don't need to encode it to json. Then every time read it from local storage try to `decode` it from json and `parse` it.

```
Future loginAuth(String email, String password) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}login");
  final loginState = GetStorage();
  final response = await http
      .post(url,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
          },
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
          }))
      .then((value) {
    var data = value.body;
    if (value.statusCode == 200) {
      log.write('user', value.body); // <--- add this
      loginState.write('login', true);
      Get.snackbar(
          "success", "Logged in as ${json.decode(value.body)['username']}");
      print(json.decode(value.body));
      Get.to(Index());
    } else if (value.statusCode == 404) {
      Get.snackbar("failed", "${json.decode(value.body)['message']}");
      print('bad login not workng, ${value.body}');
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Failed", "Failed to Login, Try Again");
      print('bad login, ${value.body}');
    }
  });
}
```

**Note** that in this way still you need call `json.decode` on the result of local storage when you try to read it.

Comment: @MohammedBekele check out my update.

Comment: one more thing how can i access one object. like if i want the email. i tried to do `json.decode(loginState.read('user')[0]['email'])` but it throws `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`

Comment: you can do this: json.decode(loginState.read('user'))[0]['email']

Comment: it throws an error `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("email")`

Comment: it said that your list is empty. are you sure you save it currectly?

Comment: yes i did it when user logs in, and i did null it when user logs out

Comment: it worked i didn't need the index